# Get all rows from a table for a particular user along with sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **real_estate** its structure and data is as follows:-

```
| id | user_id | details | location | worth

|  1 |    1    | Null    | Null     | 10000000

|  2 |    1    | Null    | Null     | 20000000

|  3 |    2    | Null    | Null     | 10000000
```

My query is the folloeing:

```
SELECT * , SUM( worth ) as sum
FROM  real_estate
WHERE user_id =  '1'
```

The result which I get from this query is

```
| id | user_id | details | location | worth    | sum

| 1  |     1   | Null    | Null     | 10000000 | 30000000
```

I want result to be like

```
| id | user_id | details | location | worth    | sum

| 1  |    1    | Null    | Null     | 10000000 | 30000000 

| 2  |    1    | Null    | Null     | 20000000 | 30000000
```

Is there any way to get the result the way I want or should I write 2 different queries?
1)To get the **sum** of worth
2)To get **all the rows** for that user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a subquery that calculates the sum for every user, and then JOIN the result of the subquery with your table:

```
SELECT real_estate.*, s.user_sum
FROM
  real_estate INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(worth) AS user_sum
                          FROM real_estate
                          GROUP BY user_id) s
  ON real_estate.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE
  user_id = '1'
```

but if you just need to return records for a single user, you could use this:

```
SELECT
  real_estate.*,
  (SELECT SUM(worth) FROM real_estate WHERE user_id='1') AS user_sum
FROM
  real_estate
WHERE
  user_id='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do your sum in a subquery like this

```
 SELECT * , (select SUM(worth) from real_estate WHERE user_id = '1' ) as sum
 FROM real_estate WHERE user_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by **id**

```
SELECT * , SUM( worth ) as sum FROM real_estate WHERE user_id = '1' group by id
```